# How to loop through list(perl) foreach?

Tags: perl

I have a problem using perl. The problem is that I would like to add multiple row into an database. Now I have an list and 1 can insert 1 row in the database. but only 1 because then I get an error because it is not unique. This is true but I would like to add more then 1 row so I found on the internet that I need to use an foreach loop but I don't know how.

Here below the script:

```
sub new{

    local $/; $_ = $text; $match=$_;
    my @splitline = split/\n/, $match;
    foreach my $Sngline(@splitline)
    {
       $bla =  print " $&\n", if($Sngline=~m/^pc([^\s]*)\s/g)
    }

} 


my $db_ora = DBIx::Simple->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=10.42.60.15;sid=centndsa;port=1521','NDSCENTR', 'NDSCENTR');

sub test {

    $db_ora->query("Select TEST1 FROM script");

}

sub ba
    {

    print new();

    $db_ora->query("insert into SCRIPT (TEST1) values(?)", $bla)  or error(DBIx::Simple->error);
    return;
    }

print ba();

print $bla;
```

**just made some adjustmends to clear things up**

```
my $db_ora = DBIx::Simple->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=10.42.60.15;sid=centndsa;port=1521','NDSCENTR', 'NDSCENTR');
sub new{

my $db_ora = DBIx::Simple->connect('dbi:Oracle:host=10.42.60.15;sid=centndsa;port=1521','NDSCENTR', 'NDSCENTR');
local $/; $_ = $text; $match=$_;
my @splitline = split/\n/, $match;
foreach my $Sngline(@splitline)
{
   $bla =  print " $&\n", if($Sngline=~m/^pc([^\s]*)\s/g);
   $bla2 =  print " $&\n", if($Sngline=~m/^pc([^\s]*)\s/g);
    $db_ora->query("insert into SCRIPT (TEST1,TEST2) values(?,?)", $bla, $bla2);
    return;
   print $bla;
   print $bla2; 

 }

}
print new();
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message you get

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops

Comment: I was wondering about the 'reason' for `$_ = $text; $match= $_;` Then I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925351/how-to-use-split-using-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be

```
$db_ora->prepare("insert into SCRIPT (TEST1,TEST2) values(?,?)", $bla, $bla2);
$db_ora->execute();
```

?

Comment: thx Ted Bear for your awnser and i already tested it out and that is not an problem anymore .

Comment: OK, but was it the answer to the problem you described?

Comment: your where right i will try to explain to you what the real problem is . I need to add multiple rows into an database using (i think ) an foreach loop . (look at the second script). with the first script  you do get the error but that is not my problem .

Answer (score -1):

the for loop seems fine.

There is, however, a semicolon missing after the if, within the loop.

```
$bla =  print " $&\n", if($Sngline=~m/^pc([^\s]*)\s/g);
```

In perl, `DO if (CONDITION);` is ok for DO being one line, otherwise `if ( ){}`

Furthermore, $bla seems to be undeclared as far as I can see here.

Comment: please check the script again made some changes

Comment: Sorry, but this is not "clearing up" for me. I told you what went wrong, you will have to work out what to do on your own.